# How to show that $3^x + 4^x = 5^x \Leftrightarrow x = 2$?

Tags: calculus

It seems (and is the case) that $x=2$ is the only solution to that equation. But how can I prove it?

My attempts:

1. Simplifying: Does not seem to work. Even WolframAlpha can not show a step-by-step solution (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3%5Ex%2B4%5Ex%3D5%5Ex).
2. Prove $3^x+4^x=5^x \land 3^y+4^y=5^y \implies x = y$. With the identity $3^2+4^2=5^2$, it follows that $x=2$ is the only solution.
3. Show $x<2 \implies 3^x+4^x<5^x$ and $x>2 \implies 3^x+4^x>5^x$. With $x=2$ as one solution, it follows that it is the only solution.

In all options, I don't know what to do next. How to prove it?

Comment: $$(3/5)^x, (4/5)^x$$ are both decreasing functions , hence their sum should give unique values

Comment: This question has been on MSE before.

Answer (score 6):

Divide both sides by $5^x$:
$$(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x=1 $$
Note that for $0<a<1$, the function $x\mapsto a^x$ is strictly decreasing, hence as in method 2, there cannot be more than one solution.